# Using setContents on CALayer causes layer to disappear until animation completes

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation

I have an NSView subclass `thumbnailView` which contains a layer hosting view `stillImage` that has a single CALayer `stillImageLayer`

When the thumbnailView is created, I set the contents of the stillImageLayer to a NSImage loaded from disk `[stillImageLayer setContents:originalImage]`

As the app is used, that image gets updated so I call `[stillImageLayer setContents:newImage]`

But I'm seeing something weird happening. The SECOND time that setContents is called on this CALayer, it disappears and reappears with the new image when the animation would have ended. I've confirmed this by wrapping the `setContents` call in a CATransaction with the animation duration set to 5 seconds.

However any subsequent calls to setContents all work as expected with the image dissolving from old to new.

This is on OS X 10.10 with the matching SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because when have animation, it display the presentation layer. You're setting contents to the model layer, so it will not show until the animation is completed.

If you want the animation to be intact, you need to reapply the animation again when setting the contents.

Comment: But the previous contents are actually disappearing from screen, which shouldn't happen when setting new contents on the CALayer. It should do an implicit animation and fade from old to new, as it does for the 3rd, 4th, 5th etc times when the contents are set.

Comment: I think you are correct. At least if your animation is not contents animation it should have worked correctly. Have you tried with CABasicAnimation?

Comment: Same result with CABasicAnimation. Totally weird. Am going to give up for now and set transition to 0 duration for consistency.